# Problems understanding the mathematical notation of the Forward algorithm in Hidden Markov Models

Tags: notation, hidden-markov-models

I found a recursive version of the [forward algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_algorithm) on wikipedia, however I don't understand the notation given in the pseudocode:
[image: pseudocode from wikipedia]

What means $$x_{t-1}$$ under the summation sign? What do I need to sum?
It would be really helpful if someone could provide a calculation example.
Thank you!